Update PhpStorm to the latest version via JetBrains Toolbox, and know the CodeGeeX plugin generates an error
After updating to the latest version of PhpStorm via JetBrains Toolbox, the CodeGeeX plugin is generating an error, and none of the available options in the error dialog work.

Despite searching extensively, I haven’t found a solution. Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Deleted the entire plugins folder
Added the plugin ID to disabled_plugins.txt
Uninstalled and reinstalled PhpStorm using Toolbox
Uninstalled and reinstalled PhpStorm without Toolbox

None of these attempts have resolved the issue.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?
I'm using MacOS M1.


Are you able to start the IDE to a point where you can see the Welcome screen or a project (and can use the menu). or this is the max what you can see? 2) If you can load the IDE -- check the idea.log file (e.g .via Help | Show Log in XXX). If cannot -- access it from Toolbox App -- try accessing that via the gear icon for PhpStorm in the Toolbox App -- it should have an option for that.


Why the above -- the log file may show the reasons or other hints. NOTE: makes sense to clear that log before trying to launch the IDE -- to see the most recent and most relevant log entries.

Next point -- remove the problematic plugin. What was the previous IDE version? Was it the same 2024.2.x or a previous (e.g. 2024.1.x etc)? Usual plugins directory on MacOs for the latest 2024.2 version would be ~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2024.2/plugins (from https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#-7t6up7_162)

The Toolbox App might use a bit diff paths (at very least it was the case for a few users a year or two ago on Windows). To check where the IDE tries to load the plugins from, check the idea.log -- at the start of the session it puts the paths it uses there -- e.g. for me on Windows: idea.plugins.path=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2024.2\plugins

It is possible that the IDE tries to load this plugin from the older IDE version config folder (if your recent upgrade was between major versions). Try removing the plugin file there as well. The following I cannot confirm, but might be possible: if you are using IDE Settings sync functionality, it's possible that the plugin is loaded from that folder. What folders do you have in plugins and  config paths? Show what you have there.

@LazyOne it seems PhpStorm was still accessing the plugin from that older version! Thank you for you help.

I finally resolved the issue!
It turns out I had multiple PhpStorm versions installed.

Initially, I deleted the plugins folder for PhpStorm 2024.3, but the CodeGeeX plugin was still present in the plugins folder for PhpStorm 2024.2. It seems PhpStorm was still accessing the plugin from that older version!
The error was completely resolved once I removed the plugin from the 2024.2 folder.

It should not do that. Unless the upgrade was incomplete, so it was trying to import the config from the previous version (every time .. since the start up was incomplete, as I understand).
